# Group Permissions Display

Tags: 2010, groups

I am new to Sharepoint; and self teaching eekks.  I am using 2010. 
I accidently removed the groups (viewing) from the main site page; however when I go to the groups they are still there and active; just not linked to the site page.  Anyone know how I can display that on the site page again?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the site page (Click Site Actions -> Edit Page). Then Add Web Part. Select "Site Users" webpart.

If you want to display users of a particular group. Then edit web part properties and select "Show people in the group"